# "create" KO mapping option for nested objects not used when primary "create" is specified

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have the following:

```
var CardViewModel = function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    this.editing = ko.observable(false);
    this.edit = function() {
        debugger;
        this.editing(true);
    };

};


var mapping = {

    'cards': {
        create: function (options) {
            debugger;  // Doesn't ever reach this point unless I comment out the create method below
            return new CardViewModel(options.data);

        }
    },

    create: function(options) {
        //customize at the root level.  
        var innerModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
        //debugger;
        innerModel.cardCount = ko.computed(function () {
            //debugger;
            return innerModel.cards().length;
        });

        return innerModel;
    }
};

var SetViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(setData, mapping);
debugger;
ko.applyBindings(SetViewModel);
```

When I run this, the 'cards' method never gets hit, so those edit properties in the CardViewModel aren't available.  I can hit that debugger if I comment out the "create" method, but I need both.  Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'cards'` is not a valid Javascript variable name. Try something else without the single quotes.

You will also  need to edit your `CardViewModel` code as `this` in the inner function refers to the inner function and will not see the knockout observable in the outer function.

```
var CardViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    this.editing = ko.observable(false);
    this.edit = function() {
        debugger;
        self.editing(true);
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I'm a bit confused about the 'cards' - I'm following the example here for defining the "children" subarray: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html  In my case, 'cards' is an array.  This method does get hit when I remove the 'create' method.

Comment: Jake, did this answer your original answer?  I'm in a similar spot right now and removing the single quotes makes no difference.  I can never use a create for a child object unless I remove the main create.

Comment: I don't understand why this is accepted. This is clearly part of the knockout syntax as noted by @JakeP. Also, nowhere in the modified CaredViewModel does it reference the mapping.